# Using a directory path variable in a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, variables, glob, quotes

I have the following `for` loop:

```
for f in /home/Some\ path\ that\ includes\ spaces/* ; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

When I run this loop, it spits out everything within `/home/Some path that includes spaces/`, as I expect. However, if I try to define the file path as a variable, like so:

```
dir="/home/Some\ path\ that\ includes\ spaces/*"
for f in "$dir" ; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

the output is just the file path itself. I'm sure there's some simple syntax I'm missing, but I haven't been able to find any information about it online.

Comment: If you expand a variable without double-quotes around it, it both splits on whitespace and expands wildcards; with double-quotes, it doesn't do either. Getting the shell to expand wildcards without splitting is ... possible, but klugy. It's better to keep your wildcards separate from the fixed parts of the path, and double-quote just the variables containing the fixed parts.

Answer (score 1):

By including the `*` into quotes, you prevent its expansion.

```
dir="/home/Some path that includes spaces"
for f in "$dir"/* ; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

Comment: Could you explain why moving the glob out works?

Comment: That solved it, thank you so much!